# ClassNotFoundException for Kafka-Spark cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run some .jar file made in scala-Spark 2.0.2. in my Spark-Kafka cluster. The code's here:

```
import java.util.HashMap



import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer,ProducerConfig}
   import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
   import org.apache.spark.streaming._
   import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._

object sparkKafka{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if(args.length < 4){
      System.err.println("Usage: sparkKafka <zkQuorum><group> <topics> <numThreads>")
      System.exit(1)
    }

val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("sparkKafka")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
ssc.checkpoint("E:/temp/")

val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val wordsCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L))
    .reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(10), Seconds(2), 2)
wordsCounts.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

}

}

I built .jar file named: *kafka-spark.jar* and scp-it to my node in **spark2** folder so it could read it. 
Afterwards I went to start the script with:

```
bin/spark-submit  --class "sparkKafka" --master local[4] kafka-spark.jar hdp2.local:2181 group1 Topic-example 1 -verbose
```

The error I'm getting is like it said in the head of topic, or ClassNotFoundException: sparkKafka

```
[root@hdp2 spark2]# bin/spark-submit  --class "sparkKafka" --master local[4] kafka-spark.jar hdp2.local:2181 group1 Topic-example 1 -verbose
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sparkKafka
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:686)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Where am I making mistake? Also I tried with full path to my jar file, but eihter I get that .jar not found or this error above. Also I tried without *-v* but I think it doesn't make any difference. 
It would be great if someone knows where is a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling it like this

```
bin/spark-submit  --class "sparkKafka" --master local[4] kafka-spark.jar hdp2.local:2181 group1 Topic-example 1 -verbose
```

If that does not work you might want to extract content of kafka-spark.jar and check if it actually contains sparkKafka class.

Comment: I said already that I tried with *-verbose* but it's the same. 
Also, I extract the files and there is a *sparkKafka.sc* file in which is *object sparkKafka* like above.

Answer (score 0):

Hava you add package in your sparkKafka.scala ?

Comment: I don't understand question :S
Maybe you want it to ask am I adding packages through Maven or? It's sbt type of "application" and I'm building jar through IntelliJ. Did I answer on your question?

Comment: I am mean that hava you add "package my.package" in your code

Comment: I tried with and without it. But neither of them works.

Comment: It is really strange

Comment: I tried also unpack my .jar file to si if .scala code like aboe is in there but, it really is. Truly don't know why he can't recognize the class.

Comment: Try to use bin/spark-submit  --class sparkKafka --master local[4] kafka-spark.jar hdp2.local:2181 group1 Topic-example 1 -verbose.

Comment: # Run application locally on 8 cores
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master local[8] \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  100

Comment: --class "sparkKafka" may be wrong,try to chang it to --class sparkKafka.hope it helpful.

Comment: With verbose and without double qoute marks I'm getting the same output of error. Don't know I'll try with different approach with building sbt and post it here if that works out

Comment: the code can work correctly in my Intellij idea,may be the jar is not correct.